# Impossible to change admin password, script gives me different hash every time (???)

Tags: authentication-authorization

Context: Drupal 9.14 installed on a small EC2 server for testing

After a composer update, my admin password stopped working (first strange event).

I decided to use the password-hash.sh to recreate one and update it directly in my MySQL database. But... it didn't work. And I noticed this strange behavior. The script is giving me a different hash each time I'm using it (if the same logic is used at login, no wonder I can't log)

```
ubuntu$ ./core/scripts/password-hash.sh "vincent" "vincent" "vincent" "vincent"

password: vincent               hash: $S$EopakPbMJyAFAGO.3sKQy5xNBSJ9Msv87Ox4fNw8hpx2SO36HWX/

password: vincent               hash: $S$EJyg6.fdWP5F7.nVhoZ7dcw/P5yxz4UEP7fFQ2yhoQu/NwzxFhu1

password: vincent               hash: $S$EO.OiLMVtIU2RwRddeXXDr.Yw288BsXK3kPIR0LrRzYbgrzltzD8

password: vincent               hash: $S$E78EyKNvURFUqEIiukjFpWR3mgSsIRyOt1PLDQGmFyIXbw5zVGvB
```

Is it normal? If not, how to solve this?

Comment: This question needs more focus. It contains two questions: 1) "Why can't I log in after composer update?" and 2) Why does this script produce different hashes for the same string? Question #1 requires more information, specifically: what did composer update? Question #2 is because of salting.

Comment: 1) Composer update of the Elasticsearch connector module.

2) Because of salting ? Are you 100% sure of that ? If so, where should I store that "moving salt" in the database ? And where can I find this salt when the hashed password is generated ?

Comment: ...and that update, alone, made it impossible for the admin account to log in? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Not saying that. I'm not sure at all it's related.

I'm more intrigued by the password script. I don't really understand its use if the salt is always changing and not given to me during the creation process.

Comment: You can research salting and PHP’s password_hash function. But it’s one question per post on this site.

Answer (score 0):

`password-hash.sh` is used to generate a hash from a plaintext password.
Each time it is executed, it returns a different value because it uses a different salt each time. That is not a problem, since the salt is part of the hash itself, which means that Drupal core is able to verify the password matches the hash.